# Angular 2 ng-bootstrap open multiple models

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to open modal on top of another model using ng-bootstrap. Model is open as expected but the modal-backdrop of the second model is behind the fist model.
[image]

Models have opend as the [document](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples). Nothing special has done.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this work as just by adding following css code.

```
.modal:nth-of-type(2) {
    z-index: 1051 !important;
}
.modal-backdrop:nth-of-type(2) {
    z-index: 1050 !important;
}

.modal:nth-of-type(3) {
    z-index: 1052 !important;
}
.modal-backdrop:nth-of-type(3) {
    z-index: 1051 !important;
}
```

I want to open 3 nested models. That's why I added  nth-of-type(2) and nth-of-type(3)